# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Spring Security or Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc

Currently my Spring application only accepts request on HTTPS protocol. Below is a portion of the `security-context.xml`

```
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true"
        disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/signup*" access="permitAll"
            requires-channel="https" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll"
            requires-channel="https" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll"
            requires-channel="https" />
        <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"
            requires-channel="https" />
        <session-management
            session-authentication-error-url="/loginFailed">
            <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"
                max-sessions="2" />
        </session-management>
        <logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    </http>
```

Now, I also would like the application to be able to redirect HTTP `GET` request to HTTPS when user visit the domain e.g from `http://mydomain.com` to `https://mydomain.com`. How can I achieve that ? Should I apply the changes in the security-context.xml, the controller or perhaps Tomcat itself ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I configured the redirection from HTTP(port 80) to HTTPS(port 443) within `server.xml` as

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="443"/>
```